# How to retrieve task output definition through REST in jBPM 6.4?

Tags: jbpm

In jBPM 6.4.Final, is there a way to retrieve the task output definitions through REST? and if not what are the other alternative ways to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

> [GET] /PROCESS_ID/tasks/users/TASK_NAME/inputs

**Description**
Returns a map with all the task input parameter definitions for the TASK_NAME task of the PROCESS_ID process. The key is the name of the input and the value is its type.

> [GET] /PROCESS_ID/tasks/users/TASK_NAME/outputs

**Description**
Returns a map with all the task output parameter definitions for the TASK_NAME task of the PROCESS_ID process. The key is the name of the input and the value is its type.

You can see the complete documentation in the following link
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.4/html/development_guide/realtime_decision_server#user_tasks